# Búsqueda por index no funciona [Mongoose]

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose

Estoy tratando de integrar búsqueda de texto a un modelo en mi aplicación, el modelo es el siguiente:

```js
import { Schema, model } from 'mongoose'

const repairSchema = new Schema({
    device: {
        trademark: { type: String, required: true },
        model: { type: String, required: true },
        imei: { type: String, required: false },
        color: { type: String, required: true },
        canStart: { type: Boolean, required: true },
        beforeRepaired: { type: Boolean, required: true },
        presentsMoisture: { type: Boolean, required: true },
        blocking: {
            hasBlocking: { type: Boolean, default: false },
            blockingType: { type: String, required: false, enum: ['pin', 'patreon', 'password'] },
            pin: { type: Number, required: false },
            password: { type: String, required: false },
            patreon: { type: Array, required: false }
        },
        reasonForAdmission: { type: String, required: true },
        state: { type: String, required: false }
    },
    customer: {
        name: { type: String, required: true },
        phoneNumber: { type: String, default: null },
        email: { type: String, default: null },
        adress: { type: String, default: null }
    },
    payment: {
        estimatedCost: { type: Number, required: false },
        prePayment: { type: Number, required: false },
    },
    invoiceId: { type: Number, required: true },
    admissionDate: { type: Date, required: true },
    deliveryDate: { type: Date, required: false },
    createdBy: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true },
    businessId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true },
    status: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true },
    branchOffice: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true },
    logs: [{
        date: { type: Date, required: true },
        username: { type: String, required: true },
        content: { type: String, required: true }
    }]
})

repairSchema.index({
    'invoiceId': 'text',
    'device.trademark': 'text',
    'device.color': 'text',
    'device.model': 'text',
    'device.imei': 'text',
    'customer.name': 'text',
})

export default model('Repairs', repairSchema, 'repairs')
```

Mi problema radica en que si realizo una búsqueda funciona todo excepto el index **'invoiceId'**

A continuación una prueba con valores del index *customer.name*:
[image: Búsqueda que sí funciona]

Ahora una que debería funcionar pero no manda nada:
[image: Ruta que no funciona]

La prueba de que el registro con invoiceId = 518 existe:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A continuación el fragmento de código donde ajusto la búsqueda de texto al query:

```js
if (req.query.textSearch) {
  query.$text = { $search: req.query.textSearch }
}

const repairs = await getRepairsByQueryService(query, '-businessId', queryOptions)
```

**Gracias de antemano a todo aquel que pueda ayudar**

Comment: Y no te funcionará, porque los índices de texto sólo funcionan sobre campos de tipo `string`. El campo `invoiceId` es numérico, por lo tanto, cuando creas el índice compuesto, dicho campo es ignorado. Saludos

Comment: Gracias por contestar, tenía el presentimiento que era por eso. Sabes si hay alguna forma de que no sea ignorado y hacer que funcione?

Answer (score 0):

## Mi solución

Lo que terminé haciendo fue cambiando el tipo de datos del campo *invoiceId* a String para que el index lo detectara